# Use specific allocator with Protocol Buffer in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, protocol-buffers

Is it possible to specify an allocator for protocol buffer so that the memory allocated by PB behind my back is done using this allocator rather than new?

I haven't found any details about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... so that the memory allocated by PB behind my back is done using this allocator rather than new?"*

I'm afraid there isn't such feature available, besides overriding the global `new()` implementation.

If you have problems regarding availability of dynamic memory management on your target, I'd recommend to use the [**nanopb**](https://code.google.com/p/nanopb/) generator and C-API. It's extremely lightweight, and doesn't need `new()` or other kind of dynamic memory management to use it at all.